Would buoyancy change in different pressure and atmospheres?
In my understanding buoyancy is the force on an object is equal to the weight of the fluid displaced by the object, and pressure increases the buoyant force. I’m wondering if the pressure was somewhat lower how would it affect overseas travel?

The bouyant force is due to the difference in pressure between the bottom and the top of the object.F = ΔP*A

What does "overseas travel" mean? Are you asking about travel on board a ship that sails on the surface of the ocean? A submarine that "sails" beneath it? An airplane or a lighter-than-air ship that flies above?

As overseas travel i mean cargo ships with over 24,000 shipping containers

Buoyancy depends on the ratio of the densities of the fluid and the buoyed object. In the case of a ship sailing on the ocean, changes in atmospheric pressure will have no significant effect on the density of either the ship or the water that it's floating in.

Buoyancy in water is independent of ambient pressure because water is incompressible.  For compressible fluids (e.g., gases) buoyancy does depend on ambient pressure.

As noted in the comments, the buoyant force relies on the existence of a pressure gradient over the surface of the object.  In other words, the pressure on the top of the object is a little lower than the pressure at the bottom, and so the object experiences a net upwards force from the fluid.  It can be shown that this difference in pressure is always equal to the weight of the displaced fluid.
So if the air pressure was lowered (somehow) by 10 kPa over the entire volume of the atmosphere, this would not cause any change in the buoyant force on an object, since the difference in pressure between top & bottom would remain the same.  On the other hand, if the air pressure was lower by 10% over the entire volume of the atmosphere (again, "somehow"), then the gradient of the pressure would also be reduced by 10% and the buoyant force would fall by the same fraction.

You say that the "difference in pressure is always equal to the weight of the displaced  fluid."   So would this mean that if I took an empty 1L milk carton and held it under water vertically, then the pressure difference between top and bottom of the carton would be the same as if I held it horizontally, because in both cases I am displacing 1kg of water?  Is there a formula to explain this?   I'm thinking that it is not just the water pressure, but the water pressure multiplied by the surface area.

@foolishmuse:  In the first case, you have a greater pressure difference acting over a smaller surface area (top & bottom of the milk carton.)  In the second case, you have a smaller pressure difference acting over a larger surface area (two of the "sides" of the carton.)  The net force comes out the same in both cases.  Mathematically, this follows from the fact that$$F_\text{buoy} = - \oint_{\partial \mathcal{V}} P , d\vec{a} = - \iiint_\mathcal{V} \vec{\nabla} P , dV = - \iiint_\mathcal{V} \rho \vec{g} , dV, ...$$

... where the first step follows from the divergence theorem and the second step follows from the hydrostatic equilibrium equation $\vec{\nabla} P = \rho \vec{g}$.

Thanks. And thank heavens that I started studying integrals on Kahn Academy last year!


I’m wondering if [atmospheric] pressure was somewhat lower how would it affect overseas travel?


[By] "overseas travel" i mean cargo ships with over 24,000 shipping containers

Buoyancy depends on the ratio of the densities of the fluid and the buoyed object. In the case of a ship sailing on the ocean, changes in atmospheric pressure will have no significant effect on the density of the ship or, of the water that the ship floats in.
